# Silverlight Control Template for ComboBox

Tags: silverlight

Using Silverlight 5.0, I have a set of checkboxes in a grid, something like this:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,10,0" Background="LightGray" Opacity="0.7" >
    <Grid Margin="5" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Content="Item 1" Margin="0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Content="Item 1A" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="2" Content="Item 2" Margin="0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="3" Content="Item 2A" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="4" Content="Item 2B" Margin="20,0,0,0" />
        <CheckBox Grid.Row="5" Content="Item 3" Margin="0" />
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

By setting the Margin, I get the effect I want, which is that Item 1A is indented under Item 1, and Items 2A and 2B are indented under Item 2.

This is just a sample, however.  There are many more of these items, so I would really rather use some kind of Binding to lay them out.

I started with a class having Name, IsSelected, and Level (0 for normal, 20 for indented) and xaml something like this:

```
<Border Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,25,10,0" Background="LightGray" Opacity="0.7" >
      <data:DataGrid x:Name="LayerOptionsGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="None"> 
          <data:DataGrid.Columns>
              <data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" />                                                     
              <data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                   <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <ContentControl >
                                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Name}" Margin="{Binding Level}" />
                             </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                   </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               </data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
           </data:DataGrid.Columns>
       </data:DataGrid>
   </Grid>
</Border>
```

What I get is a grid of CheckBoxes and Names, not too bad, but with these two major problems:  1) I haven't got the Margin working, so there is no indentation and 2) the way the Grid works, I have to click on the checkbox twice to change it (once to select, I guess).  I am looking for a better way to get this result:

```
(Checkbox) Item 1
    (Checkbox) Item 1A 
(Checkbox) Item 2
    (Checkbox) Item 2A
    (Checkbox) Item 2B
```

etc., which my initial, brute force approach provided (albeit lacking the flexibility I need).

NOTE:  if I provide a Thickness property called Margin and add Margin="{Binding Margin}" on the ContentControl, I get the indentation of the Text, but not of the CheckBox.

I am open to any options.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer while looking at the click-select part of the problem:  I replaced my whole CellTemplate with the following CellEditingTemplate:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Margin="{Binding Margin}" IsThreeState="False" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

and I also removed the line

```
<data:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" />
```

Solved both problems.